java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class with third-party SDK
I work on an Android app with a third-party partner. This third-party partner provides us with an SDK to power most of the functionality in our app. They always provide us with a new version of the library SDK plus a demo sample app of how to use it.
The latest version they shared works perfectly on their sample demo app, but it is giving us an error on our end. Usually, these updates are quite straightforward and just require us to bump the SDK library version number and that's it. However, this latest version is launching a VerifyError on our app.
The error looks like this:
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class 
com.bark.centralsdk.totkit.totorchestrator.FooCore: 
void com.bark.centralsdk.totkit.totorchestrator.FooCore.<init>(
    android.content.Context, 
    kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope,
    com.bark.centralsdk.totkit.totorchestrator.models.FooConfig,
    com.bark.centralsdk.totkit.cloudcomms.timeprovider.ticktimes.TicTakProvider) 
failed to verify: 
void com.bark.centralsdk.totkit.totorchestrator.FooCore.<init>(
    android.content.Context, 
    kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope,
    com.bark.centralsdk.totkit.totorchestrator.models.FooConfig,
    com.bark.centralsdk.totkit.cloudcomms.timeprovider.ticktimes.TicTakProvider
): [0x69B] expected to be within a catch-all for an instruction where a monitor is held (declaration of 'com.bark.centralsdk.totkit.totorchestrator.FooCore' appears in /data/app/~~XskmXtT81XvYTFEIpq7GJg==/com.bells.central.dev-RJ1CF5SRQTu7TigMxGtk9w==/base.apk!classes7.dex)
                                                                                                        at com.bark.centralsdk.belltxkit.bellcentral.FooCore.<init>(Unknown Source:671)
                                                                                                        at com.bark.centralsdk.belltxkit.bellcentral.FooCore.<init>(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                        at com.bark.centralsdk.belltxkit.bellcentral.FooCore$Companion.᫚᫚᫃(Unknown Source:526)
                                                                                                        at com.bark.centralsdk.belltxkit.bellcentral.FooCore$Companion.create(Unknown Source:11)
                                                                                                        at com.bells.central.ApplicationClass.initFoo(ApplicationClass.kt:221)
                                                                                                        at com.bells.central.ApplicationClass.onCreate(ApplicationClass.kt:160)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1316)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7848)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2486)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:9063)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:588)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)

The crash happens immediately during the Application class onCreate when we initialize the SDK.
The error is definitely on our end since the provider's sample app works as expected. I have been going one by one through all the differences between both projects, I have checked that:

We use the same compileSdk, minSdkVersion and targetSdk in both apps.

...
android {
    compileSdk 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 297


We use the same Kotlin version.

We use the same Gradle version:


distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-bin.zip


We use the same plugins:

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.22' apply false
}


We use the same compile options:

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }


The build that throws this error is a debug build that isn't minified nor obfuscated:

...
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
...

I have gone as far as to print all the dependencies I have in my app vs the latest demo version vs the previous demo version to see if they have added a new dependency that might conflict with our project:



I have also tried to enable multidex in the project, my understanding is that it shouldn't be necessary, but just in case:
...
android {
    compileSdk 34
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true

        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdk 34
...

It is extremely difficult to pinpoint this issue, so any feedback or any lead that might help me troubleshoot the issue will be considered a proper answer.
Note:

If I'm posting this question here it is because we have already raised this issue to our partner, but we haven't found a solution so far.


I usually associate a VerifyError with a bytecode incompatibility. Are you sure that the sample app is using the same version of the library that your own app is?

@CommonsWare The sample app we get doesn't even contain the actual SDK library. We get the SDK library as an aar file that we have to drop in both, the demo sample app and our app. They both are def using the same file.

I'm not exactly sure what of all the things I did actually fixed the issue so I'll list them all here:

Update everything to its latest version, Kotlin, Gradle, Compose, etc.
Rolled back the JVM to 1.7

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
        freeCompilerArgs += "-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
    }


Added these packaging opts:

packaging {
        dex {
            useLegacyPackaging true
        }
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging true
        }
    }


Added the source sets:

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

Edit: It turns out that after carefully rolling back all the changes one by one, the one that would actually trigger the issue was this:
testCoverageEnabled true

I have jacoco hooked to my project, I still don't understand how this could mess with the bytecode, but this is it.
